# LINQ join query returning null

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I've three tables.

Table A

```
id   name   des           table2     table3
1    xyz    TableA_des1    null      1
2    abc    TableA_des2    1         2
3    hgd    TableA_des2    2         3
```

Table B

```
id   name   des           Active
 1    xyz    TableB_des1   1 
 2    abc    TableB_des2   1 
 3    hgd    TableB_des2   1
```

Table C

```
id   name   des           Active
 1    xyz    TableC_des1    1
 2    abc    TableC_des2    1
 3    hgd    TableC_des2    1
```

LINQ Query

```
var res =    (from a in TableA
              where id = 1

              join b in TableB on a.table2 equals b.id into ab
              from bdata in ab.DefaultIfEmpty()
              where bdata.Active = true

              join c in TableC on a.table3 equals c.id into ac
              from cdata in ac.DefaultIfEmpty()
              where cdata.Active = true

              select new { data1 = a.name, data2 = bdata?? string.Empty, data3 = cdata?? string.Empty})
```

The about query is giving null. On debugging variable `res` has null.

Comment: That doesn't return `null` but an empty collection. Linq queries do not return `null` (unless you retrieved a specific record from it which might be null)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should avoid putting `where` conditions on range variables coming from the right side of a `left outer join`, because doing so effectively turns them into `inner join`.

Instead, you should either apply the right side filtering **before** the join:

```
from a in TableA
where id = 1

join b in TableB.Where(x => a.Active)
on a.table2 equals b.id
into ab
from bdata in ab.DefaultIfEmpty()

join c in TableC.Where(x => x.Active)
on a.table3 equals c.id
into ac
from cdata in ac.DefaultIfEmpty()

...
```

or include them in the join (when possible):

```
from a in TableA
where id = 1

join b in TableB
on new { id = a.table2, Active = true } equals new { b.id, b.Active }
into ab
from bdata in ab.DefaultIfEmpty()

join c in TableC
on new { id = a.table3, Active = true } equals new { c.id, c.Active }
into ac
from cdata in ac.DefaultIfEmpty()

...
```

In order to understand why is that, try to evaluate `where bdata.Active == true` when `bdata` is `null` (i.e. there is no matching record). Actually if this was LINQ to Objects, the above criteria will generate `NullReferenceException`. But LINQ to Entities can handle that w/o exceptions, since databases naturally support `null` values in queries for a columns which are normally non nullable. So the above simple evaluates to `false`, hence is filtering the resulting record and effectively removing the effect of a `left outer join` which by definition should return the left side record regardless of whether a matching right side record exists.

Which means that actually there is a third way (althought the first two options are preferable) - include an explicit `null` checks:

```
from a in TableA
where id = 1

join b in TableB
on a.table2 equals b.id
into ab
from bdata in ab.DefaultIfEmpty()
where bdata == null || bdata.Active

join c in TableC
on a.table3 equals c.id
into ac
from cdata in ac.DefaultIfEmpty()
where cdata == null || cdata.Active

...
```

Comment: Isn't that obvious - when there is no matching record from the right side of the join, `bdata` is `null`, hence `where bdata.Active = true` evaluates to `false` and is preventing the query to return records.

Comment: if there 10 left joins in linq, there will be performane issue

Comment: I don't think so. The number of joins doesn't matter. And filtering before joining always helps. And even it doesn't, producing a correct result is always higher priority than producing faster but incorrect result.

Comment: From my experience with EF, the option (2) will produce the best SQL.